# How can i do a for loop in the oposite direction?

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to create an script which color the zones in green where if you had gone long you would win certain % and in red zones where your stop loss would have activated. But in pine-script the for loop works from right to left. This script works but in time reversal as you can see in the figure... how can I do the same but from left to right?
This exmaple uses 10% profit, 0% stoplose
[image: Works as expected but in the past]

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
j = 0
priceH = 0.0
priceH := not na(priceH[1]) ? priceH[1] : na
priceL = 0.0
priceL := not na(priceL[1]) ? priceL[1] : na
for i = 0 to 500
    if close[i]-close > close*0.1 
        j := i
        priceH := close
        break
    else
        if close[i]-close < -close*0.00
            j := i
            priceL := close
            break

longC = color.green
shortC = color.red
trans = 80

long = close < priceL
short = close > priceH

bgcolor(color=long ? longC : shortC, transp=trans)
plot(close[j], color=color.yellow)
```

Comment: Could it be as simple as `for i = 500 to 0`?

Comment: It seems not so simple, in that case it will start counting from 500 bars in the past to the 0 one... never asking for the ones in the right side